# Eclipse STS desaparece el plug-in subclipse al reiniciarse

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Las versiones son las siguientes eclipse STS V. 3.8.2.RELEASE SO macOS Sierra subclipse V. 1.12.x.

Instalo subclipse a travez del marketplace y todo ok, puedo hacer commits, checkouts, etc. todo lo necesario a travez del plug-in, sin embargo una vez que cierro STS y lo abro de nuevo el plug-in ya no funciona, si me voy a **help --> installation details** el plug-in efectivamente ya no esta. esto no ocurre si únicamente reinicio el IDE.

También realice la instalación del plug-in agregando la url en **Available software sites** el resultado es el mismo.

De antemano muchas gracias.

--EDICION

Me acabo de dar cuenta que en donde agregue la url en **Available software sites** ya no esta después de cerrar y abrir el IDE.

Olvide mencionar que en cada ocasión que cierro el IDE y lo abro de nuevo, tampoco guarda la dirección o ruta hacia el workspace previamente seleccionado, es como si se abriera por primera ves y me muestra la ruta por defecto.

--EDICION
Ok gracias a @Luigi Mendoza encontré algunas cosas que creo que pueden ser la causa del problema aun que no se como se puedan resolver.

Cuando se instala Eclipse STS se crea una carpeta llamada **.eclipse** dentro de la ruta **/Users/$userName/** quedando **/Users/$userName/.eclipse** dentro de esta carpeta existe otra llamada **org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_1070434759_macosx_cocoa_x86_64** el numero **1070434759** no se a que corresponda. Después de instalar los plugins, dentro de la misma se crea otra llamada **plugins** en donde se almacenan los plugins descargados, no los que vienen empaquetados en la aplicación de eclipse. quedando la ruta de la siguiente forma
**/Users/$userName/.eclipse/org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_86999941_macosx_cocoa_x86_64/plugins/**., Si se dan cuenta el numero de la carpeta cambio a **86999941**

Ahora bien, después de instalar los plugins requeridos y cerrar y abrir la aplicación dos veces (específicamente dos) se crea una nueva carpeta con un numero diferente es decir **org.springsource.sts_3.8.2.RELEASE_363625953_macosx_cocoa_x86_64** ahora si observan el número es **363625953** y eso se va repitiendo cada que le instalo los plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Por los síntomas descritos, parece que tu Eclipse se encuentra en una ruta donde no puedes escribir o que el usuario con el que ejecutas la aplicación no tiene permisos para escribir en la ubicación donde está tu instalación de Eclipse (sea STS o cualquier otro IDE basado en él). Te recomiendo verificar estos elementos antes de ejecutar nuevamente, incluyendo los permisos de tu workspace (espacio de trabajo). Cuando sepas que puedes escribir realmente en estas ubicaciones, intenta nuevamente.

Para revisar si el usuario tiene permisos, te recomiendo visitar la carpeta desde el terminal y revisarla con el comando `ls -l`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, suena muy lógico lo que comentas, voy a revisar los permisos, ¿sabes en donde se instalan los plug-ins que se descargan mediante el IDE? para revisar los permisos de la carpeta en donde deberían estar.

Comment: @OJVM esta respuesta puede ayudarte: [Where is the location of 'plugins' directory for eclipse mars in mac OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33859107/1065197), y la segunda respuesta también: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34333669/1065197. En mi caso, yo descargué Eclipse y lo coloqué en una ruta local donde tengo todo el control, igual con el workspace.